# how can i upload doc, pdf and txt file in ionic1 using cordova?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How can I upload all file types in ionic framework using cord ova plugin ?

I have been trying to upload files via cord ova camera plugin for images and videos please suggest what should I use to upload doc files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ionic 1 you can use ngCordova's File Transfer plugin to achieve this. Check this [documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) for more help.

Comment: Hi
can you please tell how can we select a random file from phone using ionic.
the document uploads a static file, I want to pic a file from phone memory like we upload a photo from gallery

Comment: You can choose a file from the device using ngCordova's FileChooser2 plugin => http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it helped

Comment: i have already tried the method in ULR but its is giving me parse error

Comment: how can i upload doc, pdf and txt file in ionic1 using cordova? [on hold]?
How can I upload all file types in ionic framework using cord ova plugin ?

I have been trying to upload files via cord ova camera plugin for images and videos please suggest what should I use to upload doc files

Comment: Hi @ShubhamBansal did you get any solution for this, I also need same in my ionicv1 app?